# Combining StepExecution context late-binding and property placeholder in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I would like to access something like this "${#{stepExecution.stepName}.classificationSource}" for a property on a bean. 
This is basically a lookup of "{stepname}.String" from a property file.
But #{stepExecution.stepName} is resolved only at beforeStep by Spring batch, whereas Spring attempts to load ${..} on bean loading itself, thereby causing errors. IS there any workaround for this?

UPDATE :
As OP suggested i moved from nesting of params. I modified the property file structure so as to set on "**stepExecutionContext**" by implementing "**StepExecutionListener**" and using the "**beforeStep**" method. By setting i mean setting a value for the key **classificationSource** on the executionContext, Thereby reducing the expression to "**#{stepExecutionContext['classificationSource']}**"
 Upon debugging the setter method for this property field is invoked before the invocation of the "**beforeStep**" method, thereby not changing the field desirably. What am i missing here?
**EDIT**
My bad having the listener and bean as the same Class. Moved the listener and added in xml and its working fine.

Comment: Can't you just read the value from the properties file when you set up the job parameters and include it inside the job parameters?

Comment: If you know the step names beforehand, I can't see any reason why you can't just read them in using `@Value` in your service class when you are setting up the job. I might be wrong, if so please expand.

Comment: I do not know the step names beforehand. The usage is like the same bean used in different steps,in each the bean values(properties) changing depending on the step name.

Comment: I attempted loading the properties as JobParameters and then accessing them as #{jobParameters[#{stepExecution.stepName}.classificationSource]}. But i get the following error 'code'"Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 15): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'"'code'

Comment: Nah if you have a String value in your jobParameters, you give it a key value. If you key value is 'foo' then you access the value by using  `@Value("#{jobParameters['foo']}")`. You may need to redesign your batch jobs. I don't think Spring can do what you are wanting it to do

Comment: try `#{jobParameters[stepExecution.stepName.classificationSource]}` (nested expression aren't supported and usually only start # is required